# linkedlist remove duplication node from java

Tags: java, linked-list, duplicates

```
public void deleteDups(Node n) {
    HashSet<Object> set = new HashSet<>();
    Node previous = null;
    while (n != null) {
        if(set.contains(n.data)) {
            previous.next = n.next;
        } else {
            set.add(n.data);
            previous = n;
        }
        n = n.next;
    }
}
```

I don't know why this function can remove duplication.

Comment: what is it removing duplication?

Comment: are u familiar with hashsets?

Answer (score 0):

This is where you are bypassing the current node, if data already exists in set.

```
if(set.contains(n.data)) {
  previous.next = n.next;
}
```

In this statement, `previous.next = n.next;` the current node is bypassed and previous node's next pointer is directly referencing the current node's next pointer. So in the end the linkedList will not hold duplicate values.